# How is member function instantiated?

Tags: c++

Is a member function instantiated as long as it is called, or is it instantiated only once in the program?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class test {
public:
    test();
    void test_function_1(int iv = 0);
    void Print(void) const;
private:
    T date;
};

template<typename T> test<T>::test()
{
    date = 0;
}

template<typename T> void test<T>::test_function_1(int iv)
{
    date += iv;
}

template<typename T> void test<T>::Print(void) const
{
    cout << date << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    test<int> s;

    s.test_function_1(); 

    s.Print(); 

    s.test_function_1(100);

    s.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

When `s.Print()` is called, it will be instantiated. The next time it is called, will it be instantiated again?

Comment: What do you mean by instantiating a function? Would your question change if `print` were not a class member function?

Comment: Functions are not instantiated.  Only objects (and templates),

Comment: @PaulSanders No, functions are also instantiated. It's just a less often important detail.

Comment: @PasserBy You can instantiate objects and templates, no?  And that's all.

Comment: @PaulSanders https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.spec#temp.inst

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have a templated class and you instantiate it. So its member functions are instantiated only once as member functions of a normal class. The tricky part is **when** they are instantiated. You can check this code:

```
struct  A{};

template<typename T>
class test {
public:
    void test_function(int iv = 0) { date += iv; }
private:
    T date{};
};

int main(void)
{
    test<A> s1; // class instantiation is ok
    //s1.test_function(0); - error when calling member function

    test<int> s; // ok
    s.test_function(0); // ok

    return 0;
}
```

The class `test<A>` will be instantiated despite the fact that its member functions don't compile (because struct A doesn't provide `operator+=` for int type). Member functions are instantiated only when **required by context**. C++ standard describes this in the following way:

> **§ 14.7.1 Implicit instantiation**
>
> Unless a function template
> specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly
> specialized, the function template specialization is implicitly
> instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that
> requires a function definition to exist. Unless a call is to a
> function template explicit specialization or to a member function of
> an explicitly specialized class template, a default argument for a
> function template or a member function of a class template is
> implicitly instantiated when the function is called in a context that
> requires the value of the default argument.

Comment: Thank you for answering and I almost understand now

Comment: You can also have a look here: http://www.lcdf.org/c%2B%2B/clause14.html